# Create a Fully-Featured Environment For MIPS Assembly Development

Tags: linux, assembly, development-environment, mips

I'm giving a try to MIPS Assembly by reading the [MIPS Assembly Language Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131420445) book, but I don't know the tools that are suggested and that are optional. What I need is

- Tools that are needed
- What is the best emulator and how to configure it?

At the time I just have cross-compiled binutils targeted to `mips-elf`.

**I'm using Linux Ubuntu Hardy Heron**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[spim](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~larus/spim.html) seems to be the classic MIPS simulator.

Comment: More details and other tools?

Comment: @Nathan: spim is fairly straightforward to use. There *is* a gcc MIPS toolchain. There are also MIPS CPUs produced today in the embedded world.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [MARS](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/).